# Perl string %s specifier void context for date in sprintf

Tags: perl, printf

I am accepting user input and printing formatted output.

In my format string %s returns that it is in a void context when I supply it a date. Since its just printing I am assuming string is adequate for display of a date.

This is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print "Enter item number: ";
chomp( my $item_number = <STDIN> );

print "Enter unit price: ";
chomp( my $unit_price = <STDIN> );

print "Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): ";
chomp( my $purchase_date = <STDIN> );

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $purchase_date, '%m/%d/%Y' );

print "\n";
print "Item\t Unit\t Purchase\n\t Price\t Date\n";

sprintf( "%-3d\t%.2f\t%s\n", $item_number, $unit_price, $tp );
printf("_______________________________________\n");
```

Playing around it seems %s always has a void context in sprintf.
If I do just

```
sprintf( "%s", $tp );
```

I get exactly the same warning. 
How would I print the date in the sprintf formatted case I have? Or is there a better way in perl than sprintf?

Comment: I didn't realize that sprintf was formatting only no print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` is not an in-place function, nor does it do any printing; it only formats the string. You can `print` or do something else with its return value:

```
print sprintf( "%-3d\t%.2f\t%s\n", $item_number, $unit_price, $tp );
```

or just `printf` directly:

```
printf "%-3d\t%.2f\t%s\n", $item_number, $unit_price, $tp;
```

Sample run:

```
Enter item number: 456
Enter unit price: 5
Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): 03/10/1986

Item     Unit    Purchase
         Price   Date
456     5.00    Mon Mar 10 00:00:00 1986
_______________________________________
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `sprintf()`, note the `s`.

That function doesn't output anything but returns the formatted string. But you do nothing with that returned string, like assigning it to a variable or pass it to another function. And that's the void context Perl warns you about.

Maybe you wanted `printf()` (without `s`) or assign the result to a variable for further processing.